# How does a Tor client find the correct HSDir to connect to when fetching a "descriptor" of a hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, client, node, hsdir

It seems that a Tor client connects to a HSDir through a circuit of 3 Tor nodes when retrieving a hidden service descriptor. But to access a hidden service, a user only needs to know the .onion address of that hidden service. Therefore, how does the Tor client/onion proxy finds the correct HSDirs it should connect to when trying to establish a connection to a hidden service.